# Hide existed values from database in a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php

There are 3 options, ABC, and user already selected "A". Is it possible to automatically disable or hide option A.

I have successfully created a method that will check if the value already exists in the database. I am new to javascript. I tried using (.hide() & .show()) but no luck. Can I still use javascript inside php?

Here my's code:

```
public function check_location(){
            $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare("SELECT location FROM covers");

            if(!$stmt->execute()){
                $stmt = null;
                header("Location: ../select.php?error=statement_failed");
                exit();
            }
        
            $items = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                foreach($items as $key => $item){
                    echo '<div class="category col-md-3 me-auto">';
                    echo    '<label for="size" class="form-label mt-2 mx-2">Category</label>';
                    echo        '<select name="size" class="form-select">';
                    echo            '<option value="'.($item['location']).'">'.($item['location']).'</option>';
                    echo        '</select>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: php runs on the server and javascript runs on the browser.

Comment: You can't use JS in PHP. You could send AJAX request to PHP to return valid data after changes.. you likely can do this with JS though. You should show the generated HTML and JS. You also don't need to `echo` every line.

Comment: Can you please give ideas on how I could achieve this by using javascript?